# Makefile: is there a way to include dynamically-generated file?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with two targets, `tests` and `dist`. `tests` will generate some csv files, and dist will compress the specified files into a tar ball.

Because the resulted csv files should also be included into the tar ball, I used the following Makefile(partial)

```
.PHONY: tests # to make sure the target "tests" are not treated as files
DISTFILES=$(wildcard *.csv) # also some other files, omitted here
tests:
    chmod +x tests.sh 
    -./tests.sh # will generate some csv files
dist: tests
    tar cvzf dist.tar.gz $(DISTFILES)
```

The problem I have now is that the generated-csv files are not included into the tar ball because they were not in the directory before `make dist` was called.

So my question is, is there a way to include theses dynamically-generated files? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta)'s answer is probably the simplest. You can also use make recursively, such that the second invocation sees the generated files:

```
.PHONY: tests dist dist2

DISTFILES = $(wildcard *.csv)

tests:
    chmod +x tests.sh 
    -./tests.sh

dist: tests
    $(MAKE) dist2

dist2:
    tar cvzf dist.tar.gz $(DISTFILES)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
tar cvzf dist.tar.gz *.csv
```